# How to convert binary mask or polygon label to edge pixel label?

Tags: python, polygon, edge-detection

I have a polygon label. I want to extract only the pixel of the edge area with this value, how can I write the code? shapely also tried, but I could draw a picture about the line, but I don't know how to change it to edge binary pixel mask.

I tried : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKYBx.png)

I wantd : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYX1t.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put the code directly inside your question and try to share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also make sure your images are directly visible.